# spring security : GrantedAuthority is not importing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

i am using the spring security. I added the dependency in the pom.xml but the GrantedAuthority class is not importing in the code.
pom.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bookstore</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>bookstore</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>





        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

in the user file the UserDetails and the GrantedAuthority is not imported from the security package. the github link is
https://github.com/dishankgoyal/spring-boot

Comment: what is actual issue I can see importing fine by taking pull from your code?? try running mvn clean install from bookstore project

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.authenticationEventPublisher
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]

Comment: Your one to many relationship seems wrong defined in user entity  let me correct it in your code

Comment: I am able to run your code successfully so not sure if got correctly the issue you are facing, might be just mvn clean install might work from bookstore folder.

Comment: hi can you help in my another problem   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864967/spring-boot-database-error-datasource-org-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-or?noredirect=1#comment92644836_52864967

Comment: are you still see this issue??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919326/eoor-intellij-error-cucumber-api-cli-main

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I was able to solve it by updating spring security dependencies to the latest version and refreshing pom.xml