# spring boot database error datasource "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration”

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using the spring boot, hibernate and the my sql and i am getting the error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE] at
>   com.trial.TrialApplication.main(TrialApplication.java:15)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] ... 28 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] ... 41 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver
>   class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:224)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:176)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:83)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181] at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] ... 42 common frames
>   omitted

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bookstore</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>bookstore</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

entity class is

```
package com.trial.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    private String name;
    private String phone;

}
```

properties file is

```
server.port=8181
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
# create and drop tables and sequences, loads import.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
# database settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=oracle
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

the github repository link is https://github.com/dishankgoyal/springsBoot

How can i fix this?

Comment: Instead of posting github link you entire of your project
Provide snippets of your relevant pieces of codes here. Nobody would like to brows through the github repo to find your problem

Comment: Just for readability, consider putting the Exception in a ´´´ block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your project to be running fine at my end, few things you might try to work at your end.

1. Try changing to `spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
2. Remove `@ComponentScan()` from main class and just leave `@SpringBootApplication` there.

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class TrialApplication{    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(TrialApplication.class, args);
        }       
    }
```

3. Clean your project by project-->rebuild/clean or run command `mvn clean install` or removing `.m2/repository` or re-import project or restarting IDE/system might help.

Comment: still the same error    Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;  Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: can we connect on zoom to see your screen??

Comment: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver this is the error

Comment: i have the team viewer

Comment: @dishankgoyal also restart your machine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961220/error-creating-bean-with-name-requestmappinghandlermapping?noredirect=1#comment92830992_52961220

Comment: hello dishankgoyal and @kj007, how you did fixed this? i'm facing the same error