# Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

i am using spring boot and intellij. i am getting the error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ArrayStoreException:
>   sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException:
>   sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy   at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>     at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>     at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3526)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(AnnotatedElement.java:258)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.lang.Class.isAnnotationPresent(Class.java:3425) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:570)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.isHandler(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:177)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:218)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:189)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:136)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     ... 16 common
>   frames omitted

my pom.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

demoapplication file

```
      package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

the github link for the project is 
https://github.com/dishankgoyal/springsBoot/tree/master/demo

Comment: can you post your controller class ?

Comment: please paste your code of **DemoApplication**

Comment: Can you remove postgresql from pom, clean the project and start

Comment: I did that too but the error is stil the same

Comment: problem solved i created the new project and it runs fine

Comment: @kj007 help me please in the problem https://github.com/dishankgoyal/springsBoot/issues/4

Comment: @dishankgoyal what is the issue can you please post a question and let me know

Comment: Or is it same error you are getting posted in this question ?

Comment: Its the same as explained there is no error in the program but theannotation is not working.

Comment: @kj007 did you able to find the solution of my problem?

Comment: @kj007  could you please help me in resolving the issue                                              https://github.com/dishankgoyal/project/issues/1