# error: intellij error cucumber.api.cli.Main

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am using the intellij, maven and spring boot. when i am trying to run my application i am getting the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
```

github link
https://github.com/dishankgoyal/springsBoot/tree/master/demo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224162/intellij-idea-run-configurations-for-cucumber-runner-class/47235582#47235582

Comment: Clean project as seems first you tried to add cucumber jar and also remove postgresql dependency

Comment: i deleted the .m2 folder and again reload the dependency. the error is same. i am now using the postgresql thats why i have the postgres dependency.

Comment: and also i am gettting the error cannot resolve the symbol'SpringBootApplication'.   this is same with the every import statement.